# How to infile/store first word of line as one variable, rest of line as another

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

I have a text file I am trying to read in and store here:

```
5

chrestomathy A selection of passages from an author or authors, designed to help in learning a language

detectable Able to be discovered or identified

feldspar An abundant rock-forming mineral typically occurring as colorless or pale-colored crystals

haricot A bean of a variety with small white seeds, especially the kidney bean

pluripotent Capable of giving rise to several different cell types
```

Each line is a word followed by its definition, where the capital letter starts the definition. I don't know how to inFile/store the word and definition in separate variables since they are both strings.

I created a Templated Map class below:

```
template <typename Domain, typename Range>
class Map
{

public:
Map(int n); // number of entries in the table

~Map();

void add(Domain d, Range r); // add an entry to the table

bool lookup(Domain d, Range& r);

private:
int numEntries;

Domain* dArray;

Range* rArray;


};
```

This "Dictionary" is supposed to be an instantiation of this Map where the word is the domain and range is definition.

```
Executive::Executive(string file1)
{
int n;  

Map<string, string> Dictionary;

ifstream inFile1; 
inFile1.open("Dictionary0.txt");

inFile1>>n; 

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{

    //Dictionary.add(word, def);
    //Feel like i need to use something like this too but not sure how

}

}
```

I am wanting to read and store these values so I can later use a lookup function to check if word is in "dictionary" (file) and then print its definition. I created an Executive class to read and store.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Use `>>` to read the first word into a `std::string`:

```
std::string word;
inFile >> word;
```

Step 2: Skip the whitespace after the word:

```
inFile >> std::skipws;
```

Step 3: Use `std::getline` to read the rest of the line:

```
std::string definition;
std::getline(std::cin, definition);
```